# Align spans separately inside div using CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code:

```
<div id='div_selectores' class='row_titulo '>
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_show"></span><span id="div_selector_show"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_summarized_by"></span><span id="div_selector_summarized"></span>
    <br />
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_column_headers"></span><span id="div_selector_headers"></span>
</div>
```

where I show using `span` the label with its selectors like so:

[image: label + selector]

I would like to align the selectors on the same line but after the last text of the longest label text so in this case all would be aligned starting where the Product Range selector is.

Is it possible to do only using CSS without changing the HTML?

Comment: Give width of the longest label to all the span's with display:inline-block

Comment: Can you post your CSS code?

Comment: I haven't applied any CSS code to make it look like in the picture

Comment: you could use a table (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a fixed width for the 'label_selector' class, so the dropdown elements will be aligned at the same position:

**Edit**
Add the 'display: inline-block' as Rahul said. I used a `select` input on the following example, but `span` elements will also work.

```css
.label_selector {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='div_selectores' class='row_titulo '>
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_show">some text 1</span><select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
    <br />
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_summarized_by">some text long here 1</span><select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
    <br />
    <span class="label_selector" id="lbl_column_headers">some text really long here 1</span><select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That would only separate label and selectors 150px, I would have the same issue still. I tried for each label to find the right margin but it fails on some screens

Comment: I have added an snippet so you can see it in action

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks a lot